# Regex to match a string NOT in brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have my configuration as `[HEADER].{3}$[.FOOTER]`

I need to read this config and prepare a 2-D array where string between [] is value and string without [] is a regex to be applied.

How can I split the above string to get this array.

Idea is to get:

```
IsRegEx Value
0       [HEADER]
1       .{3}$
0       [.FOOTER]
```

So that I can apply regex to `index-1th` value and concat array back to result string.

I tried using

```
string input = "[HEADER].{3}$[.FOOTER]";
char[] delimiterChars = { '[', ']'};
string[] words = input.Split(delimiterChars);
```

But that removes [] and there is no way left then to differentiate between actual value and regex pattern in given string.

`string[] parts = Regex.Split(input , @"(?<=[.,;])")` might have worked if the splitter was `.,;`

Comment: `[HEADER].{3}$[.FOOTER]` is a regex or your real input string?

Comment: Its an input string where .{3}$ is a regex that needs to be applied to header. Basically anything between [] is a value and rest is a regex.

Comment: But if your string is `[HEADER][A-Z]{3}$[.FOOTER]`, how can you know what part is the regex or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample:

```
    string input = "[HEADER].{3}$[.FOOTER]";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<header>\[.*\])(?<body>.*)(?<footer>\[.*\])");
Match m = rx.Match( input );
```

Then gather the groups contents with

```
m.Groups[ "header" ]
m.Groups[ "body" ]
m.Groups[ "footer" ]
```

*** EDIT ***
For multiple instances, you can try this

```
  string input =  "[HEADER].{3}$[.FOOTER][.HEADER2].{2}$[.FOOTER2]";
  Regex rx = new Regex(@"\G(?<header>\[[^]]*?\])(?<body>[^[]*?)(?<footer>\[[^]]*?\])", RegexOptions.Multiline);
  Match m = rx.Match( input );      
  while( m.Success )
  {
    m = m.NextMatch();
  }
```

Comment: That will certainly work if the string is limited to 3 groups. I might have an input as [HEADER].{3}$[.FOOTER][.HEADER2].{2}$[.FOOTER2]

Comment: What if I just want to parse it by only two types. Value or pattern. The one with [] is a value, other one is a pattern. As that will be more reusable. Say like this: "[value].{3}$[.value][.value].{2}$[.value]";

Comment: Well, you can extract the '[' & ']' from the group definitions, so they are not included in the group values, with this Regex rx = new Regex(@"\G\[(?<header>[^]]*?)\](?<body>[^[]*?)\[(?<footer>[^]]*?)\]", RegexOptions.Multiline);

Comment: These regex doesnt work if I have "[HEADER].{3}$" as input. It returns only heasder and not body.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will find any number of your header and footer values (assuming you don't have anything too complicated, like nested or escaped brackets):

```
var input = "[HEADER].{3}$[.FOOTER][.HEADER2].{2}$[.FOOTER2]";
var headersAndFooters = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[.*?\]");
```

Then you can calculate what is in-between using the indexes and lengths of the matches (e.g. in the above example, the gaps from 8 to 13 is the first regex), or this regex:

```
var regexes = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=(\]|^))[^\]]+?(?=\[|$)");
```